# Can't find "schemaLocation" attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm creating a schema to validate some XML, but when it comes down to actually reading in the document, I'm getting the error:

`The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:schemaLocation' attribute is not declared.`

This is what the beginning of one of the XML files using the schema looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<envelope xsi:schemaLocation="C:\LocalPath MySchema.xsd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MySchema.xsd">
...
</envelope>
```

My validation code looks like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
Settings.Schemas.Add(@"http://tempuri.org/MySchema.xsd",
@"C:\LocalPath\ MySchema.xsd");
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\LocalPath\testxml\somefile.xml", settings);
xmlDoc.Load(reader);

ValidationEventHandler eventHander = new ValidationEventHandler(validationHandler);

xmlDoc.Validate(eventHander);
```

Comment: the space between \ and MySchema.xsd ?

Answer (score 4):

The namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema (with conventional prefix `xsd` or `xs`) is for schema documents; the `schemaLocation` attribute you want is in the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance (which has the conventional prefix `xsi` for "XML Schema *Instance* namespace").